# cvs know specific revision changes to single file

Tags: cvs

I need to find one specific revision changes done on one file.
I used cvs log filename.java command and was able to find the revision number.

I am not finding any way to get exact text changes were done to the file for that revision.

I am new to cvs and since one of our Legacy application still uses it I need to use it. I also did not find the answer here or elsewhere.

Here is the command I tried to get the revision number:

```
cvs log filename.java
```

Output:

```
----------------------------
revision <number>
date: <date>;  author: author;  state: Exp;  lines: +6 -8

Comments:
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cvs diff` to see the changes between two revisions.

For example, if the change was made in revision `1.42`, use:

```
cvs diff -r1.41 -r1.42 filename.java
```

You might prefer to use `cvs diff -u`, which uses a more reader-friendly output format.

(Another useful command is `cvs annotate` (called `blame` by some other source control systems), which shows which revision changed each line.)